# css repeat-x rightside

Tags: css, image, repeat

is it possible to repeat only right side of picture. If I have a menu button picture, there are border or stripe on left side and I only want to repeat right side(without border).

When I'm just putting `repeat-x scroll right` or just `repeat-x`, the whole picture will repeat, but I only want right side to repeat, not left or whole picture.

I hope you understand what I mean.

[image: button]

This is button example. When my button title is too long and it will need to repeat button picture.
Can I only repeat that yellow part of picture? not together with red.
PS! Cant repeat color, because button is made with cradient.

Comment: Could use clarification, demo, or even screen shot.

Comment: Why don't u make 2 pictures out of them then?

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. Can't use solid color for background? Can't just make a wider image? This is underneath a gradient?

Comment: Then it wont repeat at all if Im doing it right.

Comment: Cant use solid background, because disainer has made these buttons:P.

Comment: I make to pictures then. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no, it's not possible.

A picture has fixed-width and you can't stretch just a part of it.

Solution: use two pictures, one for the left side, with fixed size and other to the right side which you can use repeat-x to fill the remaining space.

EDIT:

If your button have a horizontal gradient, the best you can do is to make a picture wide enough to encompass "almost" all cases. The key word here is *almost* because you can always find someone with a screen wider than the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you can't use a solid color, but why not simply use a wider image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just put "no-repeat top right" is that what your meaning

Answer (score 0):

Smashing Magazine has an excellent tutorial on designing buttons with CSS:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/

Scroll down to the section *"Sliding Doors: Flexible Buttons"*, it explains exactly what you're looking for.